# How many solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 21$ given the following restrictions ...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 21$ where $x_i$, $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ is a nonnegative integer such that $0 \le x_1 \le 3$, $1 \le x_2 \lt 4$ and $x_3 \ge 15$,

**My Approach**

*My idea is to find the total number of solutions without restrictions and from that subtract the solutions with restrictions to arrive at the answer.*

Number of solutions without restrictions: $C(5-1 + 21, 21) = 12650$

**Restriction 1:** $x_3 \ge 15$
Number of solutions: $C(5-1+6,6)$ = 210

**Restriction 2:** $0 \le x_1 \le 3$
We can change the restriction to $x_1 \ge 4$ and subtract the number of solutions with this restriction from the total.

$C(5-1 + 21, 21) - C(5-1 + 17, 17) = 6665$

**Restriction 3:** $1 \le x_2 \lt 4$
We can break this restriction down into two parts: when $x \ge 1$ and when $x \ge 5$. Then subtract case $2$ from case $1$.

Case 1: $x \ge 1$.
$C(5-1 + 20, 20) = 10626$

Case 2: $x \ge 5$.
$C(5-1 + 21, 21) - C(5-1 + 16, 16) = 7805$.

Case $1$ - Case $2$ is: $2851$.

Now we can sum the restrictions and remove them from the total.

$$12650 - (2851 + 210 + 6665) = 2924$$

However, the answer in the textbook is: $106$.

> **Where is my reasoning incorrect?**

Thanks for your time!

P.S. I know that there is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879619/how-many-solutions-are-there-to-x-1-x-2-x-5-21) however, I'm not looking for the answer per se. I am more interested in why my reasoning is flawed.

Comment: Do any of these cases overlap? e.g. maybe both $x_3 \ge 15$ and $x_1 \le 3,$ such as in $3+3+15=21

Comment: You've subtracted the solutions with $x_3\geq 15$. That doesn't make sense. The solutions with $x_3\geq 15$ and $x_2\geq 1$ and no other conditions should be your base solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always begin by taking care of the lower bounds, because they can be handled automatically just by changing the variables. Let $y_1=x_1$, $y_2=x_2-1$, $y_3=x_3-15$, $y_4=x_4$, and $y_5=x_5$; these new variables are non-negative if and only if the original ones satisfy their lower bound restrictions, and

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=21$$

if and only if

$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5=21-1-15=5\;.\tag{1}$$

The number of solutions to $(1)$ in non-negative integers is

$$\binom{5+5-1}{5-1}=\binom94=126\;,$$

but we need to eliminate the solutions with $y_1=x_1>3$ and those with $y_2=x_2-1\ge 4-1=3$. In other words, you have to eliminate all solutions that have $y_1\ge 4$ or $y_2\ge 3$.

How many solutions to $(1)$ have $y_1\ge 4$? That’s just another lower bound problem. You could solve it by setting $z_1=y_1-4$, $z_2=y_2$, $z_3=y_3$, $z_4=y_4$, and $z_5=y_5$ and calculating the number of solutions of

$$z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4+z_5=5-4=1$$

in non-negative integers by the usual formula, or you could notice that if $y_2=4$ there are exactly $4$ solutions, each with one of the other variables equal to $1$ and the rest $0$, if $y_2=5$ there is just one solution, with the other variables all $0$, so there are $5$ solutions with $y_1\ge 4$.

How many solutions to $(1)$ have $y_2\ge 3$? Set $z_1=y_1$, $z_2=y_2-3$, $z_3=y_3$, $z_4=y_4$, and $z_5=y_5$, and calculate the number of solutions to

$$z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4+z_5=5-3=2\;,$$

getting $\binom{2+5-1}{5-1}=\binom64=15$.

Note that no solution to $(1)$ violates both of the upper bound conditions, so there is no overlap between the $5$ solutions with $y_1\ge 4$ and the $15$ with $y_2\ge 3$. Thus, exactly $5+15=20$ of the $126$ unrestricted solutions to $(1)$ violate the upper bounds, leaving $106$ solutions that meet the conditions of the problem.

Comment: @BrianMScott: Instructive and nicely written! (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the clean and intuitive explanation!

Comment: @JeelShah: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> How many solutions to $\ds{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5} = 21}$ where $\ds{x_{i}}$ $\ds{\pars{~i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5~}}$ is a
>   
>   *nonnegative integer* such that$\quad$
>   $\ds{\left\{\begin{array}{rcccl}
> \ds{0} & \ds{\leq} & \ds{x_{1}} & \ds{\le} & \ds{3}
> \\
> \ds{1} & \ds{\leq} &  \ds{x_{2}} & \ds{\lt} & \ds{4}
> \\
> \ds{x_{3}} & \ds{\ge} & \ds{15}&&
> \end{array}\right.}$
>   $$
> \bbx{\ds{\mbox{" However, the answer in the textbook is:}\ \color{#f00}{\large 106} "}}
> $$

The answer is given by:
\begin{align}
&\bracks{z^{21}}\bracks{\sum_{x_{1} = 0}^{3}z^{x_{1}}
\sum_{x_{2} = 1}^{3}z^{x_{2}}\sum_{x_{3} = 15}^{\infty}z^{x_{3}}
\sum_{x_{4} = 0}^{\infty}z^{x_{4}}\sum_{x_{5} = 0}^{\infty}z^{x_{5}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{\color{#f00}{21}}}\bracks{\pars{z^{4} - 1 \over z - 1}
\pars{z^{\color{#f00}{1}}\,{z^{3} - 1 \over z - 1}}
\pars{z^{\color{#f00}{15}} \over 1 - z}\pars{1 \over 1 - z}\pars{1 \over 1 - z}} \\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{5}}\bracks{\pars{1 - z^{4}}\pars{1 - z^{3}} \over \pars{1 - z}^{5}} =
\bracks{z^{5}}\bracks{1 - z^{3} - z^{4} + z^{7} \over \pars{1 - z}^{5}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{5}}\bracks{1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{5}} -
\bracks{z^{2}}\bracks{1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{5}} -
\bracks{z}\bracks{1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{5}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{-5 \choose 5}\pars{-1}^{5} - {-5 \choose 2}\pars{-1}^{2} -
{-5 \choose 1}\pars{-1}^{1} =
{9 \choose 5} - {6 \choose 2} - {5 \choose 1}
\\[5mm] = &
126 - 15 - 5 = \bbox[15px,#ffe,border:2px dotted navy]{\ds{106}}
\end{align}

Comment: Great answer ! with a generatingfunctionology approach.