# Count different monomials up to a permutation of variables in a generating function

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, generating-functions, multivariate-polynomial

Is there a clever way to count the number of different monomials, up to a permutation of the variables, of the polynomial:

$$g(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=\prod_{1 \le i_1 \lt \ldots \lt i_{n-2} \le n}{\left(1+z_{i_1}z_{i_2} \ldots z_{i_{n-3}}z_{i_{n-2}}\right)}$$

without expanding the expression?

The product has ${n \choose {n-2}} = {n \choose 2}$ factors.

For example if $n = 4$, we have:

$$g(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4) = (1+z_1z_2)(1+z_1z_3)(1+z_1z_4)(1+z_2z_3)(1+z_2z_4)(1+z_3z_4) = z_2^3 z_3^3 z_4^3 z_1^3 + z_2^2 z_3^2 z_4^3 z_1^3 + z_2^2 z_3^3 z_4^2 z_1^3 + z_2^3 z_3^2 z_4^2 z_1^3 + z_2 z_3^2 z_4^2 z_1^3 + z_2^2 z_3 z_4^2 z_1^3 + z_2^2 z_3^2 z_4 z_1^3 + z_2 z_3 z_4 z_1^3 + z_2^2 z_3^3 z_4^3 z_1^2 + z_2^3 z_3^2 z_4^3 z_1^2 + z_2 z_3^2 z_4^3 z_1^2 + z_2^2 z_3 z_4^3 z_1^2 + z_2^2 z_3^2 z_1^2 + z_2^3 z_3^3 z_4^2 z_1^2 + z_2 z_3^3 z_4^2 z_1^2 + z_2^2 z_4^2 z_1^2 + 3 z_2^2 z_3^2 z_4^2 z_1^2 + z_3^2 z_4^2 z_1^2 + z_2^3 z_3 z_4^2 z_1^2 + 2 z_2 z_3 z_4^2 z_1^2 + z_2 z_3 z_1^2 + z_2^2 z_3^3 z_4 z_1^2 + z_2^3 z_3^2 z_4 z_1^2 + 2 z_2 z_3^2 z_4 z_1^2 + z_2 z_4 z_1^2 + 2 z_2^2 z_3 z_4 z_1^2 + z_3 z_4 z_1^2 + z_2^2 z_3^2 z_4^3 z_1 + z_2 z_3 z_4^3 z_1 + z_2 z_3^2 z_1 + z_2^2 z_3^3 z_4^2 z_1 + z_2^3 z_3^2 z_4^2 z_1 + 2 z_2 z_3^2 z_4^2 z_1 + z_2 z_4^2 z_1 + 2 z_2^2 z_3 z_4^2 z_1 + z_3 z_4^2 z_1 + z_2 z_1 + z_2^2 z_3 z_1 + z_3 z_1 + z_2 z_3^3 z_4 z_1 + z_2^2 z_4 z_1 + 2 z_2^2 z_3^2 z_4 z_1 + z_3^2 z_4 z_1 + z_2^3 z_3 z_4 z_1 + 3 z_2 z_3 z_4 z_1 + z_4 z_1 + z_2^2 z_3^2 z_4^2 + z_2 z_3 z_4^2 + z_2 z_3 + z_2 z_3^2 z_4 + z_2 z_4 + z_2^2 z_3 z_4 + z_3 z_4 + 1$$

and there are $11$ different monomials up to a permutation of variables. For example $z_1 z_2^2 z_3^2 z_4^3$ is equivalent to $z_2 z_3^2 z_4^2 z_1^3$.

*SOME BACKGROUND:*

The expression is the generating function for a system of linear equations built like in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3325427/573047). For the example $n = 4$ the system is:

$$\begin{cases}
x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{23} = b_1 \\ 
x_{12} + x_{14} + x_{24} = b_2 \\ 
x_{13} + x_{14} + x_{34} = b_3 \\ 
x_{23} + x_{24} + x_{34} = b_4 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

The count is the number of degree-vectors for simple graphs with n vertices (see [OEIS A004251](https://oeis.org/A004251)). Each variable $x_{ij}$ is $1$ or $0$ whether the edge ${i, j}$ between vertices $i$ and $j$ is present or not in the graph. In the general case, the system has $n$ equations ($n={n \choose n-1}$ subsets of $n-1$ vertices), ${n \choose 2}$ variables and ${n-1 \choose 2}$ variables for each equation, and each variable appears $n-2$ times in the system.
Sometime after the original post, I noticed that the result is the same with this polynomial:

$$g(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=\prod_{1 \le i \lt j \le n}{\left(1+z_{i}z_{j}\right)}$$

This one results from a linear system (dual of the above one) where the $x_{ij}$ edge variables are grouped for every vertex, for example $x_{12} + x_{13} + x_{14} = e-b_4$ in the above example, where $e$ is the total number of edges.

I noticed also that the number of all distinct monomials should be [OEIS A005155](https://oeis.org/A005155).