# Property of the symmetric reduction of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, graph-theory, generating-functions, multivariate-polynomial

The following symmetric multivariate polynomial:

$$P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\prod_{1 \le i \lt j \le n}{\left(1+x_{i}x_{j}\right)}$$

has the following property: the number of classes of its monomials, defined as the sets of monomials that can be made equal to one another with a permutation of variables, is [OEIS A004251](https://oeis.org/A004251). This is justified [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4269147/573047) (see the bottom of that question).

For $n=2,3,4,5$ I noticed that the number of monomials of the symmetric reduction of $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ expressed with each elementary symmetric polynomial as a variable, results in the same above OEIS sequence.
See [the $n=5$ case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SymmetricReduction%5B%281%2Bxy%29%281%2Bxz%29%281%2Bxw%29%281%2Bxu%29%281%2Byz%29%281%2Byw%29%281%2Byu%29%281%2Bzw%29%281%2Bzu%29%281%2Bwu%29%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%2Cw%2Cu%7D%2C%7Be_1%2Ce_2%2Ce_3%2Ce_4%2Ce_5%7D%5D), the [the $n=4$ case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SymmetricReduction%5B%281%2Bxy%29%281%2Bxz%29%281%2Bxw%29%281%2Byz%29%281%2Byw%29%281%2Bzw%29%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%2Cw%7D%2C%7Be_1%2Ce_2%2Ce_3%2Ce_4%7D%5D) and the [the $n=3$ case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SymmetricReduction%5B%281%2Bxy%29%281%2Bxz%29%281%2Byz%29%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%2C%7Be_1%2Ce_2%2Ce_3%7D%5D).

Is this true for all values of $n$? And how could it be proved?

I noticed that in general symmetric polynomials don't have this property, for example the [symmetric reduction](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SymmetricReduction%5Bx%C2%B3%2By%C2%B3%2Bz%C2%B3%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%5D) of $x^3+y^3+z^3$ has $3$ monomials, not $1$.

Comment: I used the Mathmatica function `SymmetricReduction` to get $a(2)=2, a(3)=4, a(4)=11, a(5)=31, a(6)=98, a(7)=328, a(8)=1134.$

Comment: So the assumption is false. Thank you.